# ¿Como poder apuntar a un store procedure desde otra base de datos? ¿qué es el esquema?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de poder ejecutar un SP que tengo en otra base de datos, estuve leyendo que se realiza de la siguiente manera:

- Esta es si es una tabla `exec [NombreBaseDatos].[Esquema].[NombreSP] <argumentos>;`
- De esta manera es para un SP `exec [NombreServidorVinculado].[NombreBaseDatos].[Esquema].[NombreSP]    <argumentos>;`

Pero no entiendo cual es el `[Esquema]`, yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

`EXEC [IBGP_RTLProduccion].[schema].[spAfectacionUsuario] @SPID, @Usuario` lo tengo asi por que todo esta en el mismo servidor, pero me sigue saliendo error, alguien sabe que estoy colocando mal? Espero me puedan apoyar.

Answer (score 2):

En SQL Server, todos los objetos creados por el usuario, como tablas, triggers, vistas, procedimientos almacenados, funciones y otros pertenecen a un [esquema](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema) de la base de datos. El nombre de todos estos objetos se puede (y en ocasiones se debe) *calificar* con su esquema.

Por ejemplo, podemos tener las tablas:

```
Contabilidad.AsientoContable
dbo.Configuracion
Inventario.Articulo
RRHH.Empleado
Seguridad.Usuario
```

El siguiente nivel de calificación de nombres de objetos es el nombre de la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
Empresa1.RRHH.Empleado
Empresa2.RRHH.Empleado
Empresa3.RRHH.spListarEmpleadosActivos
```

Y finalmente, si estamos accediendo a un servidor vinculado, el nombre del servidor:

```
Servidor1.SupermercadoDeEjemplo.RRHH.Empleado
Servidor2.EscuelaDeManejo.RRHH.Empleado
Servidor2.OpticaLaVision.RRHH.Empleado
```

Etc.

Un poco más de contexto sobre los esquemas:

## Esquemas

En el artículo [Understanding a SQL Schema](https://blog.devart.com/understanding-a-sql-schema.html) (Entendiendo un esquema de SQL) dice:

> A database schema is a collection of logically connected database objects and elements, such as tables, stored procedures, views, functions, triggers, indexes, etc. The schema describes how data should be organized and how the table relationships should be built within a particular database.

Mi traducción libre:

> Un esquema de base de datos es una colección de elementos y objetos de base de datos conectados lógicamente, como tablas, procedimientos almacenados, vistas, funciones, triggers, índices, etc. El esquema describe cómo deben organizarse los datos y cómo deben construirse las relaciones de tabla dentro de una determinada base de datos.

Cada login al ser registrado en una base de datos puede indicar su *esquema default*.

[image: propiedades del login, mapeo de usuarios]

Cuándo está conectado directamente a la base de datos, esto le permite escribir consultas o instrucciones sin calificar el nombre de las tablas con un esquema, por ejemplo, si un usuario tiene como esquema default `RRHH`, podría escribir la consulta:

```
select * from Empleado;
```

Y ejecutarla sin errores. Sin embargo, este mismo usuario siempre deberá escribir el nombre de tabla calificado para acceder a tablas que no están en su esquema default:

```
select * from Inventario.Articulo;
```

Si omite el nombre del esquema, el sistema no encontrará la tabla, pues la buscará en el esquema `RRHH`.

Por otro lado, la duplicidad de nombres de tablas, vistas y otros objetos es validada a nivel de esquema, es decir, nada impide que haya dos tablas con el mismo nombre en distintos esquemas, por ejemplo:

```
RRHH.Registro
Inventario.Registro
```

Son dos nombres de tablas perfectamente válidas en la misma base de datos. Así, el motor generará resultados totalmente distintos para nuestro usuario cuyo esquema default es `RRHH` que para otro usuario cuyo esquema default sea `Inventario` si ejecutan la consulta:

```
select * from Registro;
```

Notar que estas tablas podrían tener estructuras totalmente diferentes, por lo que el resultado no variará solo en los datos.

Cuándo un usuario crea un objeto como una tabla, procedimiento almacenado, etc., si omite el nombre del esquema, dicha tabla se crea en su esquema default.

Siguiendo con el ejemplo del usuario anterior, las sentencias

```
create table Pago (idPago int not null primary key, Fecha datetime);
create table Inventario.Compra (idCompra int not null, OtroCampo int);
```

Creará las tablas

```
RRHH.Pago
Inventario.Compra
```

Un usuario o un administrador puede cambiar su esquema default con la sentencia

```
USE MiBaseDeDatos;
ALTER USER [MiUusario] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Inventario;
```

Puedes crear esquemas nuevos con la sentencia [`create schema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql), por ejemplo:

```
create schema Compras;
```

Los esquemas también se pueden eliminar y modificar con `drop schema` y `alter schema`.

A nivel de esquema se manejan permisos y otros atributos, te sugiero leer el artículo [Creación de un esquema de la base de datos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-schema) si estás interesado en el tema.

Para finalizar, usualmente las bases de datos tienen por default los siguientes esquemas:

- dbo: Es el esquema por default, si no se crean otros esquemas, todos los usuarios tendrán este esquema como default y todos los objetos pertenecerán a este esquema. Es el acrónimo de *data base owner*: **dbo**.
- guest: Esquema de invitado
- sys: A este esquema pertenecen los objetos del diccionario de datos, por ejemplo las tablas y vistas `sys.tables`, `sys.all_columns` y otras que son las que describen la propia base de datos.
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA contiene vistas y tablas de diccionario de datos en cumplimiento de la definición del estándar ISO. (El nombre del esquema también deriva del estándar).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @jachguate, esta muy completa y muy bien explicada.

Answer (score -1):

Ya pude resolverlo, era muy sencillo! Realmente es lo mismo como mandar a llamar a una tabla:

`[IBGP_RTLProduccion].[dbo].[nombreSP]`